# What are the gotchas when converting a T-SQL statement into a JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, sql-server, regex, t-sql, deno

I have a large number of T-SQL statements logged from a server I manage. I'm trying to boil them down to one instance of each.

Here's one of them:

```sql
SELECT TBLLANGUAGE.NAME AS NAME1, TBLLANGUAGE_1.NAME AS NAME2, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKCHILD, TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKPARENT, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.STYLE, TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.EXTENT, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.NATURE, TBLSOURCE.TXTTITLE, TBLSOURCE_1.TXTTITLE AS 
SURTITLE FROM ((((TBLLANGUAGE LEFT JOIN TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE ON 
TBLLANGUAGE.ID = TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKPARENT) LEFT JOIN TBLLANGUAGE 
AS TBLLANGUAGE_1 ON TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKCHILD = TBLLANGUAGE_1.ID) 
LEFT JOIN TBLLANGLANGSOURCE ON TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.IDLANGLINK = 
TBLLANGLANGSOURCE.LNGFKLANGLINK) LEFT JOIN TBLSOURCE ON 
TBLLANGLANGSOURCE.LNGFKSOURCE = TBLSOURCE.IDSOURCE) LEFT JOIN TBLSOURCE 
AS TBLSOURCE_1 ON TBLSOURCE.LNGPARTOF = TBLSOURCE_1.IDSOURCE WHERE 
(((TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKPARENT) = 8687)) OR 
(((TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKCHILD) = 8687)) ORDER BY 
IIF(TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKPARENT = 8687,'B','A'), TBLLANGUAGE.NAME, 
TBLLANGUAGE_1.NAME;
```

I want to convert that to a JavaScript RegExp, substituting runs of digits for `\d` and stuff between apostrophes into `'.*'`.

So far I've got this far with Deno:

```js
function getPattern(text: string): string {
  text = text.replace(/\(/g, "\\x28")
    .replace(/\)/g, "\\x29")
    .replace(/\$/g, "\\x24")
    .replace(/\^/g, "\\x5e")
    .replace(/\./g, "\\x2e")
    .replace(/\*/g, "\\x2a")
    .replace(/\[/g, "\\x5b")
    .replace(/\]/g, "\\x5d")
    .replace(/\?/g, "\\x3f");

  [ "\\<\s\\>", "\\<", "\\<=", "=", "\\>=", "\\>"].forEach((op) => {
    const numberPattern = new RegExp(`\\s${op}\\s(\\d+)`, "g");
    text.match(numberPattern)?.forEach((e) => {
      text = text.replace(e, ` ${op} \\d+`);
    });
  });

  //const textPattern = /'[^']*'\s/g;
  const textPattern = /\s*'.*'\s*/g;
  text.match(textPattern)?.forEach((e) => {
    //const eLength = e.length;
    text = text.replace(e, "\\s*'.*'\\s*");
  });

  return text; //.replace(/\</g, "\\x3c")
    //.replace(/\>/g, "\\x3e");
}
```

This renders the above statement as

```sql
SELECT TBLLANGUAGE\x2eNAME AS NAME1, TBLLANGUAGE_1\x2eNAME AS NAME2, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eLNGFKCHILD, TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eLNGFKPARENT, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eSTYLE, TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eEXTENT, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eNATURE, TBLSOURCE\x2eTXTTITLE, 
TBLSOURCE_1\x2eTXTTITLE AS SURTITLE FROM \x28\x28\x28\x28TBLLANGUAGE 
LEFT JOIN TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE ON TBLLANGUAGE\x2eID = 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eLNGFKPARENT\x29 LEFT JOIN TBLLANGUAGE AS 
TBLLANGUAGE_1 ON TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eLNGFKCHILD = 
TBLLANGUAGE_1\x2eID\x29 LEFT JOIN TBLLANGLANGSOURCE ON 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eIDLANGLINK = 
TBLLANGLANGSOURCE\x2eLNGFKLANGLINK\x29 LEFT JOIN TBLSOURCE ON 
TBLLANGLANGSOURCE\x2eLNGFKSOURCE = TBLSOURCE\x2eIDSOURCE\x29 LEFT JOIN 
TBLSOURCE AS TBLSOURCE_1 ON TBLSOURCE\x2eLNGPARTOF = 
TBLSOURCE_1\x2eIDSOURCE WHERE 
\x28\x28\x28TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eLNGFKPARENT\x29 = \d+\x29\x29 OR 
\x28\x28\x28TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eLNGFKCHILD\x29 = \d+\x29\x29 ORDER 
BY IIF\x28TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\x2eLNGFKPARENT = \d+,\s*'.*'\s*\x29, 
TBLLANGUAGE\x2eNAME, TBLLANGUAGE_1\x2eNAME;
```

I'm converting various components to their `\xnn` forms because the way I'm reading the documentation, apparently `new RegExp()` isn't smart enough to see an embedded `(` and not think I'm defining a group in the regular expression. That is, it doesn't seem to be sufficient simply to say

```js
const pattern = new RegExp("SELECT TBLLANGUAGE.NAME (etcetera)","gi");
```

Am I reading the docs wrong and is there a better way? And no, I don't want to write a T-SQL parser unless there's a really, really good reason.

**SOMETIME LATER**

I've essentially solved my problem, and by using a different pattern matching approach. Please see [Extracting example SQL statements from a log](https://dev.to/bugmagnet/generating-example-sql-statements-from-a-log-4cok) up on [DEV](https://dev.to).

Comment: FYI, I **strongly** suggest you get into the habit of using linebreaks and whitespace when writing. Single lines of code that are 900+ characters long are notoriously difficult to read.

Comment: This is not an issue with the RegExp constructor, but rather with the fact that there are *two* parsing operations happening: the first, when the string grammar interprets the content of the string (which it doesn't know to be a regular expression), and that grammar *also* uses the backslash for escape sequences in that context. Only then is the parsed string value passed to the constructor, which will begin the *second* parse.

Comment: Advice taken. Post updated. Thank you, @Larnu

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it almost works. I'm in the process of creating two versions of the Deno script, one using your technique and the other using a simpler, tokenising approach. I hope to put both up on dev.to . I'll probably give you the "tick" but actually use the tokeniser approach.

Comment: @bugmagnet I don't fully understand the code you've written but tokenizing is probably the correct path especially since single quotes get escaped like this inside of a string `where myfield = 'O''brian'`. I could probably modify the regex to address this specific scenario but others would likely creep up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve but if it's:

> convert this SQL statement into a valid regex which can find other SQL like it

then this would do it:

```js
var sql = `SELECT TBLLANGUAGE.NAME AS NAME1, TBLLANGUAGE_1.NAME AS NAME2, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKCHILD, TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKPARENT, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.STYLE, TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.EXTENT, 
TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.NATURE, TBLSOURCE.TXTTITLE, TBLSOURCE_1.TXTTITLE AS 
SURTITLE FROM ((((TBLLANGUAGE LEFT JOIN TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE ON 
TBLLANGUAGE.ID = TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKPARENT) LEFT JOIN TBLLANGUAGE 
AS TBLLANGUAGE_1 ON TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKCHILD = TBLLANGUAGE_1.ID) 
LEFT JOIN TBLLANGLANGSOURCE ON TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.IDLANGLINK = 
TBLLANGLANGSOURCE.LNGFKLANGLINK) LEFT JOIN TBLSOURCE ON 
TBLLANGLANGSOURCE.LNGFKSOURCE = TBLSOURCE.IDSOURCE) LEFT JOIN TBLSOURCE 
AS TBLSOURCE_1 ON TBLSOURCE.LNGPARTOF = TBLSOURCE_1.IDSOURCE WHERE 
(((TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKPARENT) = 8687)) OR 
(((TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKCHILD) = 8687)) ORDER BY 
IIF(TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE.LNGFKPARENT = 8687,'B','A'), TBLLANGUAGE.NAME, 
TBLLANGUAGE_1.NAME;`;

// First replace: account for JS regex special chars and escape with backslash to make them literal
// Second replace: get everything between single quotes and make it .+?
// Third replace: get all digit sequences and make them \d+
// Fourth replace: get all whitespace sequences and make them \s+
var sql_regex = sql.replace( /[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&' )
                   .replace( /('.+?')/g, '\'.+?\'' )
                   .replace( /\d+/g, '\\d+' )
                   .replace( /\s+/g, '\\s+' );

console.log( sql_regex );

// Test if our regex matches the string it was built from
console.log( new RegExp( sql_regex, 'g' ).test( sql ) );
```

Value of `sql_regex`:

```
SELECT\s+TBLLANGUAGE\.NAME\s+AS\s+NAME\d+,\s+TBLLANGUAGE_\d+\.NAME
\s+AS\s+NAME\d+,\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.LNGFKCHILD,
\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.LNGFKPARENT,\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.STYLE,
\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.EXTENT,\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.NATURE,
\s+TBLSOURCE\.TXTTITLE,\s+TBLSOURCE_\d+\.TXTTITLE\s+AS\s+SURTITLE
\s+FROM\s+\(\(\(\(TBLLANGUAGE\s+LEFT\s+JOIN\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\s+ON
\s+TBLLANGUAGE\.ID\s+=\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.LNGFKPARENT\)\s+LEFT
\s+JOIN\s+TBLLANGUAGE\s+AS\s+TBLLANGUAGE_\d+\s+ON
\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.LNGFKCHILD\s+=\s+TBLLANGUAGE_\d+\.ID\)\s+LEFT
\s+JOIN\s+TBLLANGLANGSOURCE\s+ON\s+TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.IDLANGLINK\s+=
\s+TBLLANGLANGSOURCE\.LNGFKLANGLINK\)\s+LEFT\s+JOIN\s+TBLSOURCE\s+ON
\s+TBLLANGLANGSOURCE\.LNGFKSOURCE\s+=\s+TBLSOURCE\.IDSOURCE\)\s+LEFT
\s+JOIN\s+TBLSOURCE\s+AS\s+TBLSOURCE_\d+\s+ON\s+TBLSOURCE\.LNGPARTOF
\s+=\s+TBLSOURCE_\d+\.IDSOURCE\s+WHERE
\s+\(\(\(TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.LNGFKPARENT\)\s+=\s+\d+\)\)\s+OR
\s+\(\(\(TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.LNGFKCHILD\)\s+=\s+\d+\)\)\s+ORDER\s+BY
\s+IIF\(TBLLANGUAGELANGUAGE\.LNGFKPARENT\s+=\s+\d+,'.+?','.+?'\),
\s+TBLLANGUAGE\.NAME,\s+TBLLANGUAGE_\d+\.NAME;
```

*Note: new lines are superficial and were only added for readability*